# Map two objects and join together

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to join the data result from ajax to the const res. 
So Ideally the list order would be

- Attack    402983
- Defense   1500
- Strength  70
- HitPoints 68

As you can see below, i'm having trouble appending the two together in a list fashion. An example of whats coming from ajax data is 402983,1500,70,68

**HTML**

```
<form class="form-inline mt-2 mt-md-0">
  <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search"/>
  <button id="search-btn" class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search </button>
</form>

<ul id="response">         
</ul>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
// this is the id of the form
  $('#search-btn').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var url = "?player=";
    var player = $('input[name="search"]').val();
    var urlAddition = url + player

    $.ajax({
      url: urlAddition,
      dataType: "html",
      success: function(data) {
        const res = 'Attack, Defense, Strength, HitPoints';
        const list = res.split(",");
        const listdata = data.split(",");
        const secondlists = listdata.map(item => + item);
        $('ul#response').html(list.map(item => '<li>' + item + secondlists + '</li>').join(''));
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: What is the output of your current code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the second param from the handler which is the index.

```
$('ul#response').html(list.map((item, i) => '<li>' + `${item} ${listdata[i]}` + '</li>').join(''));
                                      ^                                  ^
```

As you can see, this approach uses the array `listdata` directly.